# Render Rmd in Loop But Name Files on Second Variable

Tags: r, for-loop

I am creating a series of reports by rendering HTML files with the following command:

```
for (workshopid in w){
     rmarkdown::render('C:/ReportSeries/Workshops_PresenterReport.Rmd',  
                output_file =  paste("Workshop_",workshopid, '_', Sys.Date(), ".html", sep=''), 
                output_dir = 'C:/ReportSeries/temp')
```

}

As you can see, I use `workshopid` to identify subsets that define each separate report.

So far, all this works fine.

What I would like is to use a second variable (a person's last name) to appear in the `output_file`, since the files are easier to identify this way.   I'm surprised replacing `paste("Workshop_",workshopid, '_',`  with `paste("Workshop_",lastname, '_',`  does not work, since the **output_file** argument only writes a file name.

I have a list of `lastname` values that correspond with `workshopid` values.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seq_along()` to iterate over your workshop ID variables. You mention that you have a name variable that corresponds to the IDs, in which case you can use the same index to fetch the name as well.

```
wid <- c("id1", "id2", "id3")
wn <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")

for (i in seq_along(wid)) {
  print(sprintf("%s has id %s", wn[i], wid[i]))
}
[1] "name1 has id id1"
[1] "name2 has id id2"
[1] "name3 has id id3"
```